# GCP Serverless pyspark : Illegal character in path at index

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, gcloud, dataproc

I'm trying to run a simple hello world python code on Serverless pyspark on GCP using `gcloud` (from local windows machine).

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello")
```

This always results in the error

```
=========== Cloud Dataproc Agent Error ===========
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 38: gs://my-bucket/dependencies\hello.py
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:883)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.handler.AbstractJobHandler.registerResourceForDownload(AbstractJobHandler.java:592)
```

The `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud dataproc batches submit pyspark hello.py --batch=hello-batch-5 --deps-bucket=my-bucket --region=us-central1
```

On further analysis, I found that `gcloud` puts hello.py file in `dependencies\hello.py` under folder `{deps-bucket}` and Java considers backward slash `'\'` as illegal.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation?

Comment: Have you tried giving bucket name along with gs protocol? i.e. gs://my-bucket/

Comment: Yes, doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ronak mentioned, Can you double check the bucket name ? I have replicated your task, and simply copied your code to my Google Cloud shell. and it ran just fine. for your next run can you delete the dependencies folder and run the batch job again ?

See my replication here:
[image]

Dependencies path created after running the job:
[image]

Comment: I've tried to replicate it. gcloud command creates in the bucket a file with a name `dependencies\hello.py`, but it is not in dependencies folder.